# Give Lambda Invoke permission to ApiGateway with one deployment

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, serverless-framework, serverless

I wrote resources in my `serverless.yml` like below:

```
resources:
  Resources:
    RestApi :
      Type : AWS::ApiGateway::RestApi
      Properties :
        Body : ${file(./swagger.yaml)}
    LoginApiToInvokeLambda:
      Type: AWS::Lambda::Permission
      Properties:
        FunctionName: login
        Action: lambda:InvokeFunction
        Principal: apigateway.amazonaws.com
```

When I sls deploy, below error occured:

> An error occurred: LoginApiToInvokeLambda - Function not found: arn:aws:lambda:ap-northeast-1:xxxxxxxxxxxx:function:api-dev-login (Service: AWSLambda; Status Code: 404; Error Code: ResourceNotFoundException

In the initial deployment, I thought that permissions were set before creating lambda functions. Therefore, I commented out `LoginApiToInvokeLambda` in my serverless.yml. I `sls deploy` again, it succeeded. But ApiGateway does not have permission to invoke lambda. After that I restored the commented out part, and `sls deploy`. Finally I was able to give ApiGateway the permission of Lambda invoke.

Is there a way to accomplish this at the same time?

Comment: @John Rotenstein Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`DependsOn` functionality of CloudFormation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-attribute-dependson.html) in the `resources` section.

```
resources:
  Resources:
    # ...
    LoginApiToInvokeLambda:
      Type: AWS::Lambda::Permission
      DependsOn: LoginLambdaFunction
      Properties:
        FunctionName: login
        Action: lambda:InvokeFunction
        Principal: apigateway.amazonaws.com
```

I've assumed your lambda function key is `login` which gets translated to `LoginLambdaFunction`. If not, check the serverless documentation on [how the resources get named](https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/resources#aws-cloudformation-resource-reference).

In short serverless translates your configuration to a CloudFormation template, and the resources section allows you to customise what gets generated, which is why you can use `DependsOn` to solve your issue.

Comment: I was able to solve the problem by using DependsOn as you said. Thank you very much!